# Symbol from shared library not found, though defined

Tags: c++, ubuntu, shared-libraries, cannot-find-symbol

I'm working on C++ code called, via pybind11, from a Python (v3.8) application on Ubuntu 20.04.

Running the application I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
snip...
ImportError: <full-path>/<lib-name-A>.so: undefined symbol: <mangled symbol name>
```

ldd on lib-name-A output gives the absolute path to lib B in which the symbol is defined. nm -s --demangle on lib B shows the symbol is defined in the text section. Just to be sure, I compared the mangled name, and the one in lib B is identical to the one given in the error message.

So, given the library exists where ldd shows its expected, and the symbol is defined in it, why do I get the error message?

Comment: Are you sure the environments are identical between your failing Python application and your ldd application? For example, the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH may be different? Does using LD_DEBUG=files show the libraries your failing Python application loads are the ones you expect?

Answer (score 1):

> nm -s --demangle` on lib B shows the symbol is defined in the text section

The function being defined in lib B is necessary, but not sufficient. The function must also be *exported* from lib B.

Chances are, it's not. To verify, run:

```
nm -D /path/to/lib-B.so | grep $mangled_symbol_name_here
```

If my guess is correct (function is not exported), you will get no output from above command.

**Update:**

> Checking with `nm -D`, and the symbol is missing. Checking again with `-s`, the symbol has `t` (lowercase) next to it, rather than `T`

Ok, so my guess was correct.

> I've added `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` in front of the function declaration,

That's the correct solution.

> Question is why I need to declare it explicitly as visible.

Most likely because you are building this code with `-fvisibility=hidden`, which says "hide everything not explicitly declared as visible".

Building with `-fvisibility=hidden` is current best practice, but you do need to mind which symbols are used outside of the shared library you are building.

Comment: Checking with nm -D, and the symbol is missing. Checking again with -s, the symbol has t (lowercase) next to it, rather than T. So I've added __attribute__((visibility("default"))) in front of the function declaration, which solved the problem.

The function is not a class member, but rather defined in a pre-existing namespace. Seems to me the only difference between the new function and functions written before is the use of a parameter of pybind11 type. Question is why I need to declare it explicitly as visible.